# FullCalendar - How to show specific number of upcoming events in list view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar to display a list of events from a Google Calendar.
What I need is a list of the next 3 events, regardless of the day they are on.

The only option I found so far is to set the amount of days listed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: "listWeek",
        views: {
            listWeek: {
                type: 'list',
                duration: { days: 3 },
            }
        },          
    })
```

This is list is empty though, if there are no events within the next three days.

**Is there a way to set the specific amount of events displayed instead just the number of days?**

Note: My knowledge about JS is pretty basic, so if the only option is to create a [Custom View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) I'm grateful for any examples on how this could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is a conceptual problem more than a programming issue.

The short answer is:

Essentially no you can't do this using fullCalendar.

The longer explanation is:

The whole point of fullCalendar is that it displays things in a calendar-like way. Calendars are designed to highlight specific points in time - things which take place within the setting of a period of days/weeks/months. The idea of a calendar is to visualise time, and help you to place events within it and see a timeline and context for your events.

If you just want a boring old list of the next 3 events, no matter when they occur, then you're discarding the visualisation which is the entire purpose of a calendar. For that requirement, simply ditch the calendar plugin completely and just use the data you get from google to display a HTML list.